# Use a variable in a command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

This is part of the PowerShell script I am working on:

```
Write-Host $configJson.myVal
(Get-Content .\config.js) -replace "S=''", "S='$configJson.myVal';" | Set-Content .\out.js
```

The `Write-Host` part correctly displays the value in `$configJson.myVal`.

But when I run the second statement, the value that is put in the file is: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.Object].deployedBaseUrl`

How can I change the second command so that the value that is output on the `Write-Host` line is also put into the file for my replace command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a format string:

```
Write-Host $configJson.myVal
(Get-Content .\config.js) -replace "S=''", ("S='{0}';" -f $configJson.myVal) | Set-Content .\out.js
```

Comment: That worked great.  I am so inexperienced to PowerShell, I did not know about that option.

Comment: Upps, forgot the curly brackets... Thanks for the edit.